# Getting a Tibble error in R | # A tibble: 251 x 0

Tags: r

Getting an error and I can't find a solution. 
Would be awsome with some help :)

```
library(readxl)
dax <- read_excel("dax.xlsx")

diff(log(dax[,"BASF"]))

#Then i got this error:
# A tibble: 251 x 0
```

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dax[, 'BASF']` is still a `tibble` with a single column.  If we need to extract as a `vector`, use the `[[`

```
diff(log(dax[['BASF']]))
```

---

It can be reproduced with

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars_tbl <- as_tibble(head(mtcars))
diff(log(mtcars_tbl[, 'mpg']))
# A tibble: 6 x 0
```

because

```
str(mtcars_tbl[, 'mpg']) # still a tibble
#tibble [6 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ mpg: num [1:6] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
```

where as

```
str(mtcars_tbl[['mpg']]) # a vector
#num [1:6] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1

diff(log(mtcars_tbl[['mpg']]))
#[1]  0.00000000  0.08223810 -0.06336961 -0.13486740 -0.03261159
```

Comment: Thank you so much, been sitting here for 1 hour. Have a nice day :)